# How to run LibreOffice Flatpak via XWayland?

Tags: kde, libreoffice, wayland

I am running Kubuntu 21.10. I have tried Wayland a few times and it seems to be reasonably stable, with the exception of Libreoffice.

When I run LibreOffice (I use the Flatpak version and prefer to continue using Flatpak for LibreOffice), it often crashes while saving. Also contrary to X11, when LibreOffice is crashing on Wayland, it usually does not do this gracefully (meaning while on the seldom LibreOffice crash on X11, I haven't had data loss in years, I cannot say the same for Wayland).

As LibreOffice is my main working tool, I would like to try it on a Wayland session with XWayland, until the guys at the LO Foundation fix some of those Wayland bugs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Disable the sockets `wayland` and `fallback-x11` for the flatpak. On the command line, this is done with the `--nosocket=SOCKET` option, but you can also use the Flatseal tool.

Comment: Just, checked out flatseal out of curiosity...nice!